# is there a deb repository for Kafka

Tags: debian, apache-kafka

Is there any debian package repo for Apache Kafka?

I am trying to do an ansible run for the Kafka install and I see anything for Apache Kafka debian. I see some puppet modules but they are not much help for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no precompiled debian packages available for debian, bug you can use a https://github.com/tomdz/kafka-deb-packaging script to build it for yourself.

Comment: Seems to handle only kafka 0.8

Comment: @MartinSchröder there is also deb packages for confluence platform: http://docs.confluent.io/current/installation.html#installation-apt

Answer (score 2):

I found [kafka-debian](https://github.com/EnvisionX/kafka-debian) quite helpful. It wraps up the necessary commands to produce a package and install it.